# How to tell rosdep that binaries are installed?

Tags: ros, libusb, rosdep, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unable to install libusb-devel I found a [suggestion](http://groups.google.com/group/openni-dev/browse_thread/thread/fb1771b497cf5007/451a87be2b648e84?lnk=gst&q=libusb-devel#451a87be2b648e84) to install the [binaries](http://https://github.com/roxlu/OpenNI/tree/master/Source/External/LibUSB/Mac). So I did that.

But rosdep doesn't seem to know it and complains. I'm not sure that it matters (since I can't get openni to install anyway), but I wonder whether there's a way to tell rosdep that the binaries are there.

Edit:

No good way to do this in the comments so I'll ask here:

There's no libusb right now in rosdep.yaml, so would this look like the following at the end of my file?

```
libusb:
  macports: |
    # Manually installed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9307/how-to-tell-rosdep-that-binaries-are-installed?/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-03-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-03-10**:
Please mark the question answered, if/once the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simplest work around is to change the OSX definition of libusb in the rosdep.yaml file.  You can set it to point to something already installed or add a multiline script which is commented like below:

```
  macports: |
    # Manually installed
```

Update:

you will need to find the rosdep.yaml file where it is getting the definition of libusb as needed by openni.  I'm not sure what source you're running from but the following should find you the file.

`rosdep where_defined libusb1.0`

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0